# Validate input field in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, validation, textfield

I have a input field that is supposed to take numbers only.

How can I validate the string?
Would this be ok:

```
string s = "12345";
double num;
bool isNum = double.TryParse(s, out num);
```

Or does .Net have a solution for this?

Comment: TryParse _is_ a .Net solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've done looks correct.

You could also create an extension method to make it easier:

```
    public static bool IsNumeric(this object _obj)
    {
        if (_obj == null)
            return false;

        bool isNum;
        double retNum;
        isNum = Double.TryParse(Convert.ToString(_obj), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, out retNum);
        return isNum;
    }
```

So then you could do:

```
s.IsNumeric()
```

Comment: Note that this method will also allow strings that can be parsed as numbers. (i.e. If you only want digits as characters then this is not 100% correct).

Answer (score 3):

Single one line answer. Does the job.

```
string s = "1234";
if (s.ToCharArray().All(x => Char.IsDigit(x)))
{
    console.writeline("its numeric");
}
else
{
    console.writeline("NOT numeric");
}
```

Comment: This correctly answers the question as far as I can tell. Parsing the string as a double will allow characters such as "-" which I assume from the question is not the requirement. Nice and elegant too!

Answer (score 1):

your solution is ok but you could create a method that does this job for you. Bear in mind it may not work for other countries because of the culture. What about something like the below?

```
public bool isNumeric(string val, System.Globalization.NumberStyles NumberStyle)
{
    Double result;
    return Double.TryParse(val,NumberStyle,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,out result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

VB.NET has the IsNumeric function but what you have there is the way to do that in C#. To make it available app-wide just write an extension method on `string`

```
public static bool IsNumeric(this string input)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(input))
        return false;

    double result;
    return Double.TryParse(input, out result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Regular Expression Validators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650303.aspx) in ASP.NET to constrain the input.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to validate the input through the UI? I don't know if you're using asp.net, if so, the RegularExpressionValidator is normally a valid solution for this.  (http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_regularexpvalidator.asp). Hope this helps!